# Spring Web Reactive not working as war file deployed on Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have Spring Boot (2.0.0 M5) application which provides some REST API. I'd like to implement this API using `RouterFunction`s.

While I'm running app using embedded Jetty everything works fine.

When I convert the app to WAR file (following [documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)) and deploy it to Tomcat 8.5 I always get `404` when trying to call any of the endpoints.

I can see in the log that endpoints are recognised:

```
[ost-startStop-1] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/say-hello],methods=[GET]}" onto java.lang.String com.example.demo.DemoController.test()
[ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.r.f.s.s.RouterFunctionMapping: Mapped /api => {
    /v1 => {
       /status -> 
          com.example.demo.DemoApplication$$Lambda$189/1904651750@5fdc83e
   }
}
```

But when calling `curl -v http://localhost:8080/demo/say-hello` or `curl -v http://localhost:8080/demo/api/v1/status` I see default Tomcat 404 page. The path is correct, I rename .war to `demo.war` before deploying it.

Did anybody come across similar issue? You can find the code [here](https://github.com/belo82/demo-webflux).

Comment: Any errors? Have you checked Tomcat console for errors?

Comment: yes I did. No errors. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the WAR deployment model is not supported in Spring Boot for WebFlux at the moment. Spring Framework does support that model (although I'm not sure it supports deploying an app to a non-root context).

You can always create an issue on [the Spring Boot issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues), but I'm not sure this will be implemented, as deploying to a Servlet container is not the primary focus there (and you can't do that with Netty).

Quick note: adding `@EnableWebFlux` is a signal that you'd like to take the WebFlux configuration in your own hands and that Spring Boot should not auto-configure things for you in that space.

Comment: What other possibilities are there to deploy, if not WAR?

Comment: An executable JAR with an embedded server.

Answer (score 0):

Answering it now just in case some one else is still facing this issue.

In the POM file, you need to exclude the netty and add tomcat separately.

```
compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux') {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter- 
    reactor-netty'
}
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

Please check the link for full code : https://github.com/sushantkr16/Spring-boot2-webflux-annotation